# ngMessages: how to hide or show one message after the other

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<div id="messageArea">
   <div ng-messages="text1.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">
         Text1 is required ...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div ng-messages="text2.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">
         Text2 is required ...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div ng-messages="text3.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">
         Text3 is required ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div>Text1<input id="text1"  ng-model="text1" name="text1" ng-required="true"></div>
<div>Text2<input id="text2"  ng-model="text2" name="text2" ng-required="true"></div>
<div>Text3<input id="text3"  ng-model="text3" name="text3" ng-required="true"></div>
```

I wanted to show one error message at a time. When the first error is solved then the next error message will show. Anyone has any idea how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the inputs in a form tag with an ID you can use ng-messages on the form to pick up errors from all the inputs. You can see this here: http://jsbin.com/tikufuvawe/2/edit.

```
<form name="userDetails">
  <input name="userName" type="number" ng-model="number" required ng-maxlength="2" />
  <textarea name="text" type="text" ng-model="text" required></textarea>
  <div ng-messages="userDetails.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

EDIT:

I have updated my example http://jsbin.com/zadojamifo/3/edit using `ng-show` to hide other errors such that only one will show at a time. Its not a great solution but works for the situation described.

```
<div ng-messages="userDetails.number.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">number is required</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-messages="userDetails.text.$error" ng-show="!userDetails.number.$error.required">
    <div ng-message="required">text is required</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-messages="userDetails.other.$error" ng-show="!userDetails.number.$error.required && !userDetails.text.$error.required">
    <div ng-message="required">other is required</div>
  </div>
```

As you can see the `ng-show` will get bigger and bigger in size if more validation types are added and if more controls are added that require validation.

Comment: How would you handle the case where there are four required fields. Your example does not give any information on which is which.

Comment: I'm don't think it is possible to identify the control that is giving the error in `ng-messages`. The only way I can think for doing that would be to have multiple ng-messages blocks that are shown one at a time, using ng-if.

Comment: what if there are more fields how can we handle then ? giving !before&!beforesecond overtime does not looks tidy although it does the trick

Answer (score 2):

Nice solution is use CSS and ng-class

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);
```

```css
.error-wrapper {
    color: red;
}

.error-wrapper > .view {
    display: block;
}

.error-wrapper > .view ~ .view{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <form ng-submit="createWallet()" name='testForm' novalidate>
        <div>
            <input ng-model='text1' type="text" name='text1' placeholder='text1' required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input ng-model='text2' type="text" name='text2' placeholder='text2' required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input ng-model='text3' type="text" name='text3' placeholder='text3' required>
        </div>

        <div class="error-wrapper">
            <div ng-class="{ view: testForm.text1.$invalid }" class="error" ng-messages="testForm.text1.$error">
                <div ng-message='required'>Text1 required</div>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="{ view: testForm.text2.$invalid }" class="error" ng-messages="testForm.text2.$error">
                <div ng-message='required'>Text2 required</div>
            </div>
            <div ng-class="{ view: testForm.text3.$invalid }" class="error" ng-messages="testForm.text3.$error">
                <div ng-message='required'>Text3 required</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

It's show only the first error message with class `.view`, at the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kBSpRJLs6QA2D0jctKXB?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is too late but this is my solution, use ng-messages-multiple to show one or more message, angular respect the order of validation messages:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="login()">
 <label>Email</label>
    <input required name="email" type="email" ng-model="email">
    <div ng-messages="loginForm.email.$error" ng-show="loginForm.email.$dirty && loginForm.email.$invalid" ng-messages-multiple>
         <div ng-message="required">El email es requerido!</div>
         <div ng-message="email">El email debe cumplir con el formato: email@dominio.com!</div>
    </div>
  <label>Contraseña</label>
    <input required name="password" type="password" ng-model="password" ng-pattern="passwordPattern" md-maxlength="12">
    <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$invalid">
         <div ng-message="required">La contraseña es requerida!</div>
         <div ng-message="pattern">Se requieren de 6 a 12 caracteres, por lo menus un dígito, una letra mayuscula y una minúscula</div>
    </div>
  <div layout="row"  layout-align="center center">
    <button ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid>Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<div id="messageArea">
   <div ng-messages="number.$error">
   <div ng-message="required">
       Number is required ...
   </div>
</div>
<div ng-messages="text.$error" ng-if="!number.$error">
   <div ng-message="required">
      Text is required ...
   </div>
</div>
```

In this case you show the second block of messages only if the first one does not exists (and it's hidden if number.$errors exists)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this doesn't work. Only the first message will appear. When the first message is gone, the second does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

This sample (http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/05/how-to-use-ngmessages-in-angularjs.html) uses a follow solution:

```
<div ng-messages="my_form.first_name.$error" 
ng-if="interacted(my_form.first_name)">


$scope.submitted = false;
$scope.submit = function() {
  $scope.submitted = true;
};
$scope.interacted = function(field) {
  return $scope.submitted || field.$dirty;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show on page load but either on page submit or on change of value then use

```
<form name="frmSome">


  <div ng-messages="userDetails.$error"
       ng-if='frmSome.userName.$dirty || frmSome.$submitted'>
       <span ng-message="required">Name is Required</span>
       <span ng-message="maxlength">Max. 100</span>
  </div>
  <input name="userName" type="text" 
         ng-model="model.name" 
         ng-required='true' 
         ng-maxlength="30" />
  ..............................
  ..............................
  <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

- If you touch the text box it will be "dirty"
- if try to submit the page "Submitted"
- It works on the name not the model